# Chamando uma função javascript para executar uma lógica com dados que extraio do html

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

Estou pegando uns dados de um html e necessito chamar um Javascript para gerar um parâmetro com os dados que peguei no html.

Como faço para chamar o Javascript para executar sua lógica com os dados extraídos dentro de uma classe? o Javascript está abaixo. Ressaltando que o o programa está em .NET.

```
function gerarParametro(chlg) {

   var start = aux3.charCodeAt(0);
   var end = aux4.charCodeAt(0);
   var arr = new Array(aux5);
   var m = Math.pow(((end - start) + 1), aux5);

   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
       arr[i] = aux3;

   for (var i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) {
      for (var j = aux5 - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
         var t = arr[j].charCodeAt(0);
         t++; arr[j] = String.fromCharCode(t);
         if (arr[j].charCodeAt(0) <= end) {
            break;
         } else { 
            arr[j] = aux3; 
         } 
       }

       var chlg = arr.join("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Então você precisa passar os dados para o servidor .net, é isso? Se for, precisa usar ajax.

Comment: Decidi fazer a lógica em VB.net.

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver compartilhe a resposta conosco.